# How to set local storage in TestCafe before the page initialization

Tags: e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to set local storage to bypass Login screen before the page is initialized by Testcafe. I tried injecting custom scripts but that is not working.

Can someone please help me how to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

To set local storage variables in TestCafe sessions, you can use [ClientFunction's](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info.html). You could set your local storage variable with your key in a beforeEach hook, so that it's called before every single one of your tests. The code to achieve this could look like the following:

```js
const setLocalStorageItem = ClientFunction((key: string, value: string) => window.localStorage.setItem(key, value));

const getLocalStorageItem = ClientFunction((key: string) => window.localStorage.getItem(key));

fixture(`My tests`)
  .page("https://www.my-test-url.com")
  .beforeEach(async (t) => {
    await setLocalStorageItem("myLocalStorageKey", "myValue");
  });

test('Some test', async (t) => {
  // This assertion should be fine for every test
  await t.expect(await getLocalStorageItem("myLocalStorageKey")).eql("myValue");

  // more test code should follow here
})
```

As TestCafe clears the [localStorage and sessionStorage after each test](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/pull/1590), you'd need to do if you want to have access to the same local storage key/value pair in every test (or it needs to be set for each test for some reason).

if you wish to set the local storage entry only for a specific test, you could proceed as follows:

```js
test('Some other test', async (t) => {

  // my test code
}).before(async (t) => {
  await setLocalStorageItem("testKey", "testValue");
});
```

Comment: "As TestCafe clears the localStorage and sessionStorage after each test..." do concurrent tests share the localStorage while it exists, or does each test have its own `localStorage`?

Comment: Concurrent tests do not run in same browser window. Hence, they won't share the same Localstorage. You can find more information regarding concurrent test execution with TestCafè [here](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403626/guides/intermediate-guides/run-tests-concurrently).

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting the local storage item in a `beforeEach`, but in my case, I found that it was getting set too late for my needs. I was able to get things working by using the [clientScripts](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402783/reference/test-api/fixture/clientscripts) function. So, it looks something like this:

```
fixture(`My tests`)
  .page("https://www.my-test-url.com")
  .clientScripts({
    content: 'window.localStorage.setItem("myKey", "myValue");'
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I encountered the same issue with before being to late.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a nearly perfect use case for TestCafe Roles.
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402845/guides/advanced-guides/authentication

Do whatever is needed within the role to set local storage (for instance, perhaps a user signs in), then just call the useRole function for your test to start from that known local storage state in the browser.